# How is PowerShell DateTime::Parse() processing broken in certain locales?

Tags: powershell

When using [DateTime]::Parse in PowerShell under a non-US locale, like 'English (United Kingdom)', it is unable to correctly process the default [DateTime] output correctly.

```
$datetime = [DateTime]::Parse('2024-02-09T12:32:37.0286549+00:00')
[DateTime]::Parse($datetime)

02 September 2024 12:32:37
```

(Please note that under ISO 8601 which [DateTime]::Parse [supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-8.0#StringToParse) this should be 9th February, not 2nd September)

Sometimes it completely falls over under the weight of its own output.

```
$datetime1 = [DateTime]::Parse('2024-01-25T10:59:31.0141932+00:00')
[DateTime]::Parse($datetime1)

Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [DateTime]::Parse($datetime1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

Any ideas why this happens, or workarounds (apart from 'Don't presume that the output of [DateTime]::Parse is reversible in every locale?)

Comment: Why are you calling Parse twice?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - I'm just trying to demonstrate the issue - firstly, Parse() doesn't properly accept ISO 8601 in certain cultures (the first example), and secondly, sometimes it can't even process the string output of its own culture (the second example).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-8.0#StringToParse

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon CurrentCulture is LCID 2507 / Name en-GB / DisplayName English (United Kingdom). Providing an ISO 8601 standard date should not result in different behaviour depending on the culture, the whole point is that it's an international standard (see link above).

Comment: @Minkus It shows no such thing. Skip the second call to `[datetime]::Parse` and you'll see it correctly parsed `2024-02-09T12:32:37.0286549+00:00` as Feb 9th.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Replied to you below. I can see I'm wrong on the first point. I still think the second is true?

Comment: I've updated the question a little to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you first parse a string with a deterministic format:

```
$datetime = [DateTime]::Parse('2024-02-09T12:32:37.0286549+00:00')
```

... and then re-parse a non-deterministic string representation of the resulting value:

```
# [datetime]::Parse accepts string input, so PowerShell has to call 
# `$datetime.ToString()` to produce a valid parameter argument
[datetime]::Parse($datetime)
```

If you stop after step 1 you're basically done - there is absolutely no need to call `Parse` twice.

---

If you *insist* on doing it twice, make sure you explicitly format the datetime value before passing it off to `Parse` again:

```
[datetime]::Parse($datetime.ToString('o'))
# or
[datetime]::Parse($datetime.ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\:ss.fffffffzzz'))
```

Although, again, this is completely unnecessary - the same way you wouldn't need to call `[int]::Parse($number)` if `$number` already contains a value of type `[int]`

Comment: Thanks. I can now see where you're coming from on the 'don't call Parse twice' thing. In terms of the issue I'm having, it will help if I explain that between the first and second call I'm putting the value through a process that can't take a DateTime value, only a string (https://github.com/dsccommunity/ActiveDirectoryDsc/issues/702) I am looking for a way to do that safely.

Comment: It seems that converting DateTime to a string using the 'default' ToString() formatting and then reading it back in via Parse() works in the 'default' en-US culture, but in other cultures it's necessary to determine the format using ToString('o') or similar, or else you get issues... Which is frustrating.

Comment: @Minkus I understand the frustration, but that is the solution: _always_ explicitly format the string for the purpose at hand

Comment: Thanks. This should help resolve the issue I’ve been working on - a DSC resource which someone else wrote and tested in an en-US culture with the assumption that it would always work - but breaks for me :)